# Oracle JDBC driver ORA-01843: not a valid month error

Tags: oracle, jdbc, localization, liquibase

I have a SQL script containing many INSERT statements which I execute through the  Liquibase Maven `update` goal.
Some of the INSERT statements contain dates, like the below statement

```
Insert into  T (date) values ( to_date('16-JAN-12','DD-MON-RR'))
```

When I run the Liquibase `update` goal I get the following error

```
SEVERE 12/10/15 15.46: liquibase: install.xml: migrations/install/data/data.xml::1::gdm: Change Set migrations/install/data/data.xml::1::gdm failed.  Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month
 [Failed SQL: Insert into  T (date) values ( to_date('16-JAN-12','DD-MON-RR'))]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:316)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:122)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1247)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1230)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:548)
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:51)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:73)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:210)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:190)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:325)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseUpdate.doUpdate(LiquibaseUpdate.java:33)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseUpdateMojo.performLiquibaseTask(AbstractLiquibaseUpdateMojo.java:30)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute(AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:394)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:202)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:45)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:933)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1075)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1718)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1678)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:332)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:314)
    ... 35 more
```

In Internet I found that this is an error regarding the `NLS_LANG` variable which has to be set on client and server (Oracle DB), but both the platforms seem to run with `EN` language.

Have you ever experienced such a problem? What can be the issue?

Thank you
Giulio

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Insert into  T (date) values ( to_date('16-01-2012','DD-MM-RRRR'));
```

It is much safer. Number of the month is invariant to the language specified int session NLS_PARAMETER. Also year number uses all 4 digits.

```
Insert into  T (date) 
values(to_date('16-JAN-2012','DD-MON-RRRR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American'));
```

If you insist on month names you can explicitly define the territory.

Comment: I cannot edit the script, which is given to me as is

Comment: then you must execute `alter session set nls_...` before you execute the script.

Comment: I think this is the only right answer possible in my case.

Comment: Is there any way to automatically interpret and find the right(s) locale(s) which apply to the script? This way I could leave the "alter session set nls_..." part to an automatic tool in spite of asking any SQL developer to tell me which is the locale.